# Qt- Adding custom XML from Android resource

Tags: android, c++, xml, qt, ant

I'm developing application with Qt Creator. I just want use layout for specific Dialog.I created XML, but how to add this XML to project?

I added this xml on main_activity's directory  (*myApplication\android-source\res\layout*)

[image]

but when I try to compile, I get this error after creating this:

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\1ADDDT\android-sdk2\android-sdk2\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\1ADDDT\android-sdk2\android-sdk2\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

And I Should I add this XML to resource (.qrc) or what?

Here is my build.xml:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use *tools:context* as one of attribute and set it to **.MainActivity** .

Comment: Instead of adding SOLVED to the title, you might want to click the check-mark on your answer. That also marks the question solved.